# Iiyama monitor disconnects frequently over USB-C in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, usb-power-delivery

I have been using Dell XPS 13 9370 with Lenovo 4K monitor connected with USB-C cable only (USB-hub for mouse + keyboard, power delivery 60 W) and it was working smoothly.

Recently I bought a new monitor for another working location. It is 27" iiyama ProLite XUB2792QSN-B5. I used the same setup but suddenly the monitor is disconnecting from laptop randomly. This monitor has 65 W PD and a lower resolution. I even decreased the frequency to minimum, exchanged the cable to 40 Gbps but nothing helps.

Unfortunately, I cannot return this monitor. I use only one monitor, the laptop lid is closed. Vendor says that no drivers are needed. Any idea how to fix this?

```
Event Type  Event Time  Device Name Description Device Type Drive Letter    Serial Number   Vendor ID   Product ID  Vendor Name Product Name    Firmware Revision   USB Class   USB SubClass    USB Protocol    
Unplug  07.01.2024 17:56:33 Port_#0003.Hub_#0003    ASIX AX88179A USB 3.2 Gen1 to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter  Vendor Specific     01234567890000  0b95    1790    ASIX Electronics Corp.      2.00    ff  ff  00  
Unplug  07.01.2024 17:56:33 Port_#0006.Hub_#0003    USB Input Device    HID (Human Interface Device)            0bda    1100    Realtek Semiconductor Corp.     1.01    03  00  00  
Unplug  07.01.2024 17:56:33 Port_#0001.Hub_#0002    Generic USB Hub Unknown         0bda    5411    Realtek Semiconductor Corp.     0.02    00  00  00  
Unplug  07.01.2024 17:56:33 Port_#0001.Hub_#0003    USB Input Device    HID (Human Interface Device)            1bcf    0005    Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.      0.14    03  01  02  
Unplug  07.01.2024 17:56:33 Port_#0002.Hub_#0003    USB Composite Device    Unknown         413c    2113    Dell Computer Corp.     1.08    00  00  00  
Unplug  07.01.2024 17:56:33 0000.0014.0000.001.002.000.000.000.000  USB Input Device    HID (Human Interface Device)            413c    2113    Dell Computer Corp.     1.08    03  01  01  
Unplug  07.01.2024 17:56:33 0000.0014.0000.001.002.000.000.000.000  USB Input Device    HID (Human Interface Device)            413c    2113    Dell Computer Corp.     1.08    03  00  00  
Plug    07.01.2024 17:56:34 Port_#0001.Hub_#0002    Generic USB Hub Unknown         0bda    5411    Realtek Semiconductor Corp.     0.02    00  00  00  
Plug    07.01.2024 17:56:34 Port_#0003.Hub_#0003    ASIX AX88179A USB 3.2 Gen1 to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter  Vendor Specific     01234567890000  0b95    1790    ASIX Electronics Corp.      2.00    ff  ff  00  
Plug    07.01.2024 17:56:34 Port_#0006.Hub_#0003    USB Input Device    HID (Human Interface Device)            0bda    1100    Realtek Semiconductor Corp.     1.01    03  00  00  
Plug    07.01.2024 17:56:34 Port_#0001.Hub_#0003    USB Input Device    HID (Human Interface Device)            1bcf    0005    Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.      0.14    03  01  02  
Plug    07.01.2024 17:56:34 Port_#0002.Hub_#0003    USB Composite Device    Unknown         413c    2113    Dell Computer Corp.     1.08    00  00  00  
Plug    07.01.2024 17:56:34 0000.0014.0000.001.002.000.000.000.000  USB Input Device    HID (Human Interface Device)            413c    2113    Dell Computer Corp.     1.08    03  01  01  
Plug    07.01.2024 17:56:34 0000.0014.0000.001.002.000.000.000.000  USB Input Device    HID (Human Interface Device)            413c    2113    Dell Computer Corp.     1.08    03  00  00
```

Comment: If you have a powered USB-C hub, see if that can handle the increased load. However, according to https://iiyama.com/gl_en/products/prolite-xub2792qsn-b5/, it uses 21W and comes with an AC 100 - 240V, 50/60Hz power supply -- why not use it?

Comment: I want to use PD from a monitor to a laptop, not vice versa, if this is what you are saying. It is a cool functionality when you have a single cable to a laptop; no charging cable, no cable for external mouse and keyboard.

Comment: I am connecting the monitor with HDMI now and it works. But this is a big disappointment and loss of money. I could buy a similar monitor for half the price. I also selected it because it has speakers - but it sounds terribly. It was a big mistake to buy this iiyama monitor. Their support refused to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look there : https://www.asix.com.tw/en/support/download
and download the latest driver for the Ethernet ICs ASIX AX88179A.
Keep me posted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi David. Why I should download this driver? The trouble is not related to Ethernet because it happens even when a cable is disconnected.

Comment: My bad, I saw ASIX USB ethrenet on the log .. so I jumped straight into the Ethernet. Anyway, there must be something with some driver related to the dock. While it's plug n play there has to be a driver. Did you send a message to the iiyama support team ?